# getPastEvents on localhost is not a function error

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, events, nodejs

Now, I'm working on an Ethereum Blockchain project to transfer the ownership of stored devices by using local web3 provider  at the truffle environment.

- Truffle v5.0.27 (core: 5.0.27)
- Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
- Node v10.15.3
- Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37

**Browser details

- OS: [Windows 10]
- Browser tried both [firefox, chrome]
- MetaMask Version [7.0.1]

Hence, I'm attempting to query all past events that a contract has ever emitted by using the following code

```
App.contracts.DeviceManager.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    DeviceManagerContractInstance= instance;
    DeviceManagerContractInstance.getPastEvents('allEvents',
    { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' })

    .then(events => console.log("events:",events))
    .catch((err) => console.error("err",err));
     })
```

but I was getting this error

```
TypeError: DeviceManagerContractInstance.getPastEvents is not a function
```

Also, I tried to use allEvents()

```
 DeviceManagerContractInstance.events.allEvents()
.on('data', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

However, it's throwing the same error.

I don't know what is missing, and if the problem belongs to localhost or, code syntax.

Any Idea,

Comment: What's `DeviceManager` and how it is constructed?

Comment: DeviceManager is my contract.

Comment: How is it constructed? ie it is a web3 contract or a truffle contract. Perhaps it is not being assigned correctly and `DeviceManagerContractInstance` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

1st lets clear a few things for you.

- Past events are not stored in `contract`.
- There are no built in `functions` like `getPastEvents()` and `events.allEvents()` to get
  all events.
- Events are fired only where you `emit` them.

Here is an example `contract`

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract SillyOwner {
    address owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    event OwnerChange(
        address oldOwner,
        address newOwner
    );

    function changeOwner(address _no) public { 
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Insufficient permission");
        address ow = owner;
        owner = _no;
        emit OwnerChange(ow, owner);
    }
}
```

Here `OwnerChange` event will only be emitted when `changeOwner()` is called and the `require` statement returns `true`.

Example frontend:

```
const receipt = await this.SillyOwnerInstance.changeOwner(accounts[1], { from: accounts[0] });
console.log(receipt.logs);
```

You will have the emited event object available inside `receipt.logs`.

And again after calling `changeOwner()` a bunch of times there is not way to determine how many times the event was emitted and what were the values.